# Calling Documents.Open for Word.Application Error converting msoFalse to type Object

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office, automation, microsoft-word-2013

How can the `Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog` method be invoked by powershell with all the parameters supplied at least up to the point that word documents open without errors, dialogs, or macros; and that documents that are password-protected will fail with no popup/dialog that a user must dismiss?

---

Attempting to open a document with Microsoft Office Word 2013 through powershell works for basic uses of the `Documents.Open` method. Attempting to open files that contain macros or contain password protection results in an error or dialog that a person must manually dismiss. This process runs through hundreds of thousands of files, so any delays are time prohibitive.

I have attempted to use the `Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog` method to bypass these dialogs and open read-only and possibly corrupted files. Below is a sample of the code I have used to open a file.

```
# Enable Office core libraries
Add-type -AssemblyName office

#  Doc open parameter array
$DOCOpen = @{}
$DOCOpen.FileName=[string]"<Full Path to File>"
$DOCOpen.ConfirmConversions=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
$DOCOpen.ReadOnly=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$DOCOpen.AddToRecentFiles=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
$DOCOpen.PasswordDocument=$Null
$DOCOpen.PasswordTemplate=$Null
$DOCOpen.Revert=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$DOCOpen.WritePasswordDocument=$Null
$DOCOpen.WritePasswordTemplate=$Null
$DOCOpen.Format=[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOpenFormat]::wdOpenFormatAuto
$DOCOpen.Encoding=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding]::msoEncodingOEMUnitedStates
$DOCOpen.Visible=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
$DOCOpen.OpenAndRepair=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
$DOCOpen.DocumentDirection=[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDocumentDirection]::wdLeftToRight
$DOCOpen.NoEncodingDialog=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$DOCOpen.XMLTransform=$Null
$DOCOpen.OpenConflictDocument=[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse

# Create MS Office object
$appWord = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

# Set application objecs not visible
$appWord.visible = $False

# Supress alerts or dialogs
$appWord.DisplayAlerts = "wdAlertsNone" # $wdAlertsNone # 

# Supress document macros
$appWord.AutomationSecurity = "msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable"

# Word specific settings
$appWord.ScreenUpdating = $False
$appWord.DisplayRecentFiles = $False
$appWord.DisplayScrollBars = $False

$DOCDocument = $appWord.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog($DOCOpen.FileName, $DOCOpen.ConfirmConversions, $DOCOpen.ReadOnly, $DOCOpen.AddToRecentFiles, $DOCOpen.PasswordDocument, $DOCOpen.PasswordTemplate, $DOCOpen.Revert, $DOCOpen.WritePasswordDocument, $DOCOpen.WritePasswordTemplate, $DOCOpen.Format, $DOCOpen.Encoding, $DOCOpen.Visible, $DOCOpen.OpenAndRepair, $DOCOpen.DocumentDirection, $DOCOpen.NoEncodingDialog, $DOCOpen.XMLTransform)
```

The outcome of this process looks similar to the following:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At <Full path to file>\temp_Test_PowerShell_Code.ps1:41 char:3
+   $DOCDocument = $appWord.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog($FileRec.FileN ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException
```

I also attempted to make use of the `documents.open` method:

```
$DOCDocument = $appWord.Documents.Open($FileRec.FileName, $DOCOpen.ConfirmConversions, $DOCOpen.ReadOnly, $DOCOpen.AddToRecentFiles, $DOCOpen.PasswordDocument, $DOCOpen.PasswordTemplate, $DOCOpen.Revert, $DOCOpen.WritePasswordDocument, $DOCOpen.WritePasswordTemplate, $DOCOpen.Format, $DOCOpen.Encoding, $DOCOpen.Visible, $DOCOpen.OpenConflictDocument, $DOCOpen.OpenAndRepair, $DOCOpen.DocumentDirection, $DOCOpen.NoEncodingDialog)
```

In which case I receive the following result:

```
Exception setting "Open": Cannot convert the "msoTrue" value of type "MsoTriState" to type "Object".
At <Full path to file>\temp_Test_PowerShell_Code.ps1:41 char:3
+   $DOCDocument = $appWord.Documents.Open($FileRec.FileName, $DOCOpen. ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

According to the a Visual Basic reference for [opennorepairdialog](http://157.56.25.106/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.opennorepairdialog.aspx) and a .NET reference for [Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.opennorepairdialog?view=word-pia), the parameters for the method are system objects which powershell seems to have difficulty generating in the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the macro issue. I added

```
$application.AutomationSecurity = "msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable"
```

right after

```
$application.visible = $False
```

and then to put `AutomationSecurity` back the way it was I added

```
$application.AutomationSecurity = "msoAutomationSecurityByUI"
```

just before

```
$application.quit()
```

Files with macros get parsed for the search term without any popups.